# Calculating averages in SQL Server without ignoring null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query like below:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
     EmpName VARCHAR(10)
   , Qty     INT
   , Item    VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES ('Jane',3,'Dog')
     , ('Carle',1,'Cat')
     , ('Abay',5,'Goat')
     , ('Jane',1,'Dog')
     , ('Carle',10,'Cat')
     , ('Jane',2,'Dog')
     , ('Jane',8,'Goat')
     , ('Jane',3,'Ram')
     , ('Carle',2,'Dog')

--SELECT * FROM @t

SELECT 
    EmpName, [Dog], [Cat], [Goat], [Ram]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         EmpName, Qty, Item 
     FROM @t) AS b
PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR Item IN ([Dog], [Cat], [Goat], [Ram])) AS p
```

And the result is as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to calculate the average Qty across Item without ignoring null values in the calculation. For example, in row 1, `EmpName` Abay should be 5 divided by 4 (number of columns), as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

How do I get the average column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the `PIVOT` query, so here is an alternative using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Empname,
    Dog     = SUM(CASE WHEN Item = 'Dog' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    Cat     = SUM(CASE WHEN Item = 'Cat' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    Goat    = SUM(CASE WHEN Item = 'Goat' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    Ram     = SUM(CASE WHEN Item = 'Ram' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    Average = SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0))/ 4.0
FROM @t
GROUP BY EmpName;
```

Note that this will only work if you only have 4 `Item`s. Otherwise, you need to resort to dynamic crosstab.

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/616476)</kbd>

---

For dynamic crosstab, I used a temporary table instead of a table variable:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    Empname' + CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN Item = ''' + Item + ''' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Item) + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM #t
) t;

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0)) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Item) * 1.0 FROM #t) AS [Average]'  + CHAR(10) +
'FROM #t
GROUP BY EmpName;';
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/616477)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of `AVG` and `ISNULL`, i.e. `AVG(ISNULL(Dog, 0))`.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is:

```
select empname, goat, cat, dog, ram,
       (coalesce(goat, 0) + coalesce(cat, 0) + coalesce(dog, 0) + coalesce( ram, 0)
       ) / 4.0 as average
from t;
```

Another simple method uses `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, v.average
from t outer apply
     (select avg(coalesce(x, 0))
      from (values (t.goat), (t.cat), (t.dog), (t.ram)
           ) v(x)
     ) v(average);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we replace "/4.0" with the column name because we can't always assume that we have 4 columns.

Comment: @dLight . . . Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
        DECLARE @t TABLE 
        (
             EmpName VARCHAR(10)
           , Qty     INT
           , Item    VARCHAR(12)
        )
        INSERT INTO @t 
        VALUES ('Jane',3,'Dog')
             , ('Carle',1,'Cat')
             , ('Abay',5,'Goat')
             , ('Jane',1,'Dog')
             , ('Carle',10,'Cat')
             , ('Jane',2,'Dog')
             , ('Jane',8,'Goat')
             , ('Jane',3,'Ram')
             , ('Carle',2,'Dog')


        SELECT EmpName
             , [Dog]
             , [Cat]
             , [Goat]
             , [Ram]
             ,p.total/4.0 as av
        FROM (SELECT EmpName, Qty, Item,SUM(qty)OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName) AS total FROM @t) AS b
        PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR Item IN([Dog],[Cat],[Goat],[Ram])) AS p
```

```
EmpName    Dog         Cat         Goat        Ram         av
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
Abay       NULL        NULL        5           NULL        1.250000
Carle      2           11          NULL        NULL        3.250000
Jane       6           NULL        8           3           4.250000
```

**V2: Dynamic script:**

```
    CREATE TABLE #t 
            (
                 EmpName VARCHAR(10)
               , Qty     INT
               , Item    VARCHAR(12)
            )
            INSERT INTO #t 
            VALUES ('Jane',3,'Dog')
                 , ('Carle',1,'Cat')
                 , ('Abay',5,'Goat')
                 , ('Jane',1,'Dog')
                 , ('Carle',10,'Cat')
                 , ('Jane',2,'Dog')
                 , ('Jane',8,'Goat')
                 , ('Jane',3,'Ram')
                 , ('Carle',2,'Dog')
    INSERT #t ( EmpName, Qty, Item )VALUES('Abay',100,'abc')


    DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(MAX),@cnt INT 
    SELECT @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',[','[')+Item+']',@cnt=ISNULL(@cnt+1,1) FROM #t GROUP BY Item
    PRINT @cols
    PRINT @cnt
    SET @sql='SELECT EmpName, '+@cols+',p.total*1.0/'+LTRIM(@cnt)+' as av'+CHAR(13)
             +' FROM (SELECT EmpName, Qty, Item,SUM(qty)OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName) AS total FROM #t) AS b'+CHAR(13)
             +' PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR Item IN('+@cols+')) AS p'
    EXEC(@sql)
```

```
EmpName    abc         Cat         Dog         Goat        Ram         av
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
Carle      NULL        11          2           NULL        NULL        2.600000
Jane       NULL        NULL        6           8           3           3.400000
Abay       100         NULL        NULL        5           NULL        21.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please replace the hard coded value (4) and see if you get the same result? I tried to but could not get the same result as in your query above.

Comment: @dLight I updated my answer, can the v2 help you， in that case ,the items is dynamic list

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpName
     , [Dog]
     , [Cat]
     , [Goat]
     , [Ram]
     ,(isnull(p.cat,0)+isnull(p.dog,0)+isnull(p.Goat,0)+isnull(p.Ram,0))/4.0  as average
FROM (SELECT EmpName, Qty, Item FROM @t) AS b
PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR Item IN([Dog],[Cat],[Goat],[Ram])) AS p
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'.

Comment: @dLight please check it now.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything else is fine but I do not want to hardcode the value - 4 in the query. We want it to come from the column as this may vary in another table.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid NULL from your pivot sentence and compute AVG.

```
;with ct as
(
SELECT EmpName
     , ISnull([Dog],0) Dog
     , ISnull([Cat],0) Cat
     , ISnull([Goat],0) Goat
     , ISnull([Ram],0) Ram
FROM (SELECT EmpName, Qty, Item FROM @t) AS b
PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR Item IN([Dog],[Cat],[Goat],[Ram])) AS p
)
select empname, avg(dog) dog, avg(cat) cat, avg(goat) goat, avg(ram) ram
from ct
group by empname;


+---------+-----+-----+------+-----+
| empname | dog | cat | goat | ram |
+---------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|   Abay  |  0  |  0  |   5  |  0  |
+---------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|  Carle  |  2  |  11 |   0  |  0  |
+---------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|   Jane  |  6  |  0  |   8  |  3  |
+---------+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks but no average column